# Font face in html for label (Appcelerator Titanium)

Tags: android, fonts, label, appcelerator

I would need to set the font face in the html attribute of a label but I don't know how to set it. What I need is to set the font face on a specific part of the html.

Here are samples that don't work :

```
$.lbl.html = '<b>Detail : </b><font face="assets/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf"></font>';
$.lbl.html = '<b>Detail : </b><font face="FontAwesome.ttf"></font>';
$.lbl.html = '<b>Detail : </b><font face="FontAwesome"></font>'; // works on iOS
```

I have a doubt about the font path.

Is it possible to do it ? What is the path of the font path ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the font file to `/app/assets/fonts/`, and you can just use the name of the font, no need to source to a path.

Comment: I've already the font in this directory called as it works on iOS and the icon is displayed when I set the font: { fontFamily: "FontAwesome" } property on the label on android.
I am looking for a way to specify the font in the html on Android...

Comment: just use the font name in the css, no need to include it ;)

Comment: I have update my initial question because I know the tss way to set font for a label, but I do need to keep the default font for the html (ie Helvetica) and set FontAwesome on a sub part of the html. On iOS (with attributed string module https://github.com/FokkeZB/ti-html2as ) it is possible. I've read somewhere that Android now accepts "html font face", but I am unable to find the value of the html font face property